# Как можно заставить джанго выполнить генерацию заново?

Tags: ajax, django

У меня есть корзина, в которую я добавляю товары через ajax, и мне нужно в модальное окно корзины также добавить эти товары, но без перезагрузки страницы. Как можно или получить данные моделей от Django, или заставить заново генерировать участок кода в корзине?

```
$( ".add_to_cart" ).submit(function(e,addr) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var quantity = $(this).find('select option:selected').val();
        console.log(quantity);
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: String($(this).data("action")),
        data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken, quantity: quantity
            },
        success: function() {} 
      });
});
```

Comment: Никак. То, что делает django - делается на стороне сервера. Вы пытаетесь реализовать функционал фронтенда. Реализуйте api-методы в django для выдачи данных, и рисуйте изменения с помощью js.

Comment: В `Django` есть `JsonResponse`, делайте на его основе `API`.